# Recoding data and swapping integer levels in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm cleaning a data frame, in which data has been encoded erroneously. I'd need to recode some of the data in a given variable in such a way that I swap the numbers used to represent an integer level, e.g. for var1: 2s should be 3s, and 3s should be 2s.

Is there a more concise way of doing it for a slightly larger number of variables (~20) than the code below?

Starting point (df):

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4),var2=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),var3=c(5,5,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8),var4=c(4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,1,1))
```

Desired outcome (df):

```
df2 <- data.frame(var1=c(1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,4),var2=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,5,5,4,4),var3=c(8,8,6,6,7,7,7,5,5,5),var4=c(7,7,8,8,9,9,5,5,1,1))
```

Current code:

```
df1$var3[df1$var3==5] <- 55
df1$var3[df1$var3==8] <- 88

df1$var3[df1$var3==55] <- 8
df1$var3[df1$var3==88] <- 5
```

Comment: Do u have only a single pair to swap for each column?

Comment: Akrun: No, I've updated the MWE, the most complex situation is now represented by var4: 4 into 7, 5 into 8, 6 into 9, and 7 into 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use function `recode()` from dplyr:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df1$var1
 [1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
> recode(df1$var1, `2` = 3, `3` = 2)
 [1] 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 4
```

[Here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/recode) and [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/recode.html) are links with more information and documentation regarding the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mapvalues` from `plyr` as below:

```
plyr::mapvalues(df1$var1, from = c(2, 3), to = c(3, 2))
#[1] 1 1 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

For readbility and assuming the values cannot be reassigned with a pattern, I would favour using `case_when` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    var1 = case_when(
      var1 == 2 ~ 3,
      var1 == 3 ~ 2,
      TRUE ~ var1
    ),
    var2 = case_when(
      var2 == 4 ~ 5,
      var2 == 5 ~ 4,
      TRUE ~ var2
    ),
    var3 = case_when(
      var3 == 5 ~ 8,
      var3 == 8 ~ 5,
      TRUE ~ var3
    ),
    var4 = case_when(
      var4 == 4 ~ 7,
      var4 == 5 ~ 8,
      var4 == 6 ~ 9,
      var4 == 7 ~ 5,
      TRUE ~ var4
    )
  )

# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    var1  var2  var3  var4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     8     7
# 2     1     1     8     7
# 3     3     2     6     8
# 4     3     2     6     8
# 5     3     3     7     9
# 6     3     3     7     9
# 7     2     5     7     5
# 8     2     5     5     5
# 9     2     4     5     1
# 10    4     4     5     1
```